# Postgres - How to prevent locking when parent table is updated whenever an insert/delete occurs in child table

Tags: postgresql, database-design, locking

I have a simple use case wherein I update the parent table when a row is inserted/deleted in the child table.

Suppose we have a **Products** table and **Items** table and **ProductId** is the foreign key in the **Items** table.

Whenever an item is inserted or deleted in the **Items** table, an update is made in the Products table corresponding to the item. An update is simply a query like:

```
UPDATE "Products" SET "PropertyX" = $1, "UpdatedAt" = $2 WHERE "Id" = $3
```

**Problem:**

If the items inserted/deleted in the items table correspond to the same product in the products table then the database load increases considerably causing timeouts even for 3K reqs/min due to **Lock:transactionid** waits.

I tested this on Aurora Postgres (with 4 CPUs, 16G Ram) and this happens even if the number of rows in the Items table is in the thousands and the number of rows in the Products table is in the hundreds. I used .net core with entity framework.

Comment: You can't "prevent" locking; you need to tune your transaction performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to use a “deferred constraint trigger” to update the `"Products"` table whenever `"Items"` is modified.

Such triggers are `AFTER` triggers that are not run immediately after the statement, but at the very end of the transaction.

The advantage here is that the rows in `"Products"` won't be locked any longer than necessary, and your concurrency will be much better.